# Fixing Contact Form 7 on Yahoo Email address

Tags: php, email, content-management-system, contacts

I'm trying to fix my problem regarding the plugin **contact form 7**. Basically the objective of my contact form is once the user submitted their application form with resume the contact form will send an email to the sender that their message has been received.

The problem is it works on a **gmail** address but not on yahoo address.

Here is the [website](http://digitalspin.ph/federalland/application-form/) that i am developing at the moment

I tried creating my own custom form and it works for yahoo email address. Has anyone tried fixing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a problem with contact form 7 too. Contact form 7 did not send me email to Gmail. 
Contact form 7 made an update and now that I have applied the update it been working. Try applying the update to the plugin. it may just work for you now.